# $_SERVER empty for unknown reasons

Tags: php, iis, ssl, nginx, dns

My script is installed on several different servers (I have no access to them) and I've a problem with the following code.

```
$domain = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
$usersip = isset($_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']) ? $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] : $_SERVER['LOCAL_ADDR'];
```

For reasons that I'm not going to explain (not relevant) it's crucial for me to get these two values, along with others, on my own system. I'm successfully collecting all these values with `CURL()` or `fsockopen()` on most of servers but some of them are giving me a headache.

I don't know why a small amount of these servers always return me empty values for `$domain` and `$usersip` but I can find all other values. It's clear that this is not an issue with `CURL()` or `fsockopen()` but with servers unable to determine `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']`, `$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']` and `$_SERVER['LOCAL_ADDR']` for unknown reasons. In fact it's not possible that my script is installed in servers with no IP address and domain name.

I did a lot of research and I have 3 theories.

1. I'm sending all data with `CURL()` or `fsockopen()` on a non-SSL page but the "source" page is running SSL but I have a lot of other servers where the SSL against non-SSL connection is running fine so I don't think that this is the reason why it is not working also because, as I said above, I can find all values with the exception of `$domain` and `$usersip`
2. Nginx and IIS messing up with superglobal variable `$_SERVER` ([example 1](https://github.com/Jasig/phpCAS/issues/74), [example 2](https://recalll.co/app/?q=php%20-%20$_SERVER[%27SERVER_NAME%27]%20returns%20someone-else-domain.com)) still for unknown reasons
3. DNS issue with servers unable to resolve IP/domain name. If this is really the reason why it's not working, then how is possible that websites on this servers can work properly?

Comment: "why a small amount of these servers" - Do you have more information on these -or at least some of these- servers, e.g. which software (version) they are using et al?

Comment: $_SERVER was is usually empty when you call your script from the command line instead of using a proxy_pass from nginx